# Object is possibly 'undefined'. TS2532

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, viewcontext

I keep getting Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532 and I know that it's due to assignment of  setViewer to undefined, which I have done for the purpose of login matching but I came across with another problem. Right now, I have 2 data coming in homeviewer and one of them is announcements and when I try to access the data, it gives me TS2532 error. Here are the code below. I am new to these and I don't know what to change for the setViewer (`setViewer: () => undefined`) in order it for to work.

homeViewer.ts

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

import { HomeViewer } from '../types/home_viewer';

export interface ViewerContextType {
  viewer?: HomeViewer;
  setViewer: (home: HomeViewer) => void;
}

export const ViewerContext = createContext<ViewerContextType>({
  viewer: {},
  setViewer: () => undefined,
});
```

That takes interface from

```
export interface HomeViewer {
  user?: User;
  announcements?: Announcement;
}
```

The part where I use it

```
const { viewer } = useContext(ViewerContext);

  const data = viewer?.announcements;

  console.log(data[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your issue is revolving around accessing elements at specific indexes from `data` – where `data` possibly has a value of `undefined` (as per your `HomeViewer` interface);

```
export interface HomeViewer {
 user?: User;
 announcements?: Announcement;
}
```

To me, it appears that the `Announcement` type is indicative of an array of some elements (judging by the way you're accessing its data), or `undefined` (since it's optional).

Meaning, it will never certainly be an instance of `Announcement`'s type declaration, so you'll have to chain an optional access operator for accessing array elements that possibly don't exist: `?.`;

```
const { viewer } = useContext(ViewerContext);
const data = viewer?.announcements;

console.log(data?.[0]) // -> Ok!
console.log(data[0])  //  -> Err! Object is possibly undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because if **viewer** is **undefined** then **data** will also be **undefined**, and you can't do **data[0]** because is the same as **undefined[0]**